# How to access other users' files via Terminal in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, permission

I am an admin that wants to access other users' files. How to do this via the Terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by patrix: the personal files of other user's on the same machine are generally stored in the `/Users/<username>` folder for each user. The permissions on these folders are usually set such that they are private to the individual who owns the files.

This means you need to use [sudo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) to elevate your own access levels in order to see their files. If you are truly an admin, using `sudo` is something that's ok, but do so with caution. If you are not an admin then you shouldn't have the proper `sudo` privileges to do any of this and your repeated attempts to use `sudo` are logged in the system access log.

To simply list files in another user's home directory (let's call them `bob`) you do:

```
sudo ls ~bob
```

The `~` prefix is POSIX shorthand for "home directory of...". To browse freely, you can *become* that user with `sudo` like so:

```
sudo su - bob
```

This makes you `bob`, logged in as `bob` and in `bob`'s home directory. You can now move around, `cat` files, `open` files, etc. as `bob`.

Comment: When I become Bob, do I have to write su for each command?  Can I move files to my account?

Comment: Once you become `bob` with `sudo su - bob` you no longer need to prefix each command with `sudo`. You are `bob` at that point and can see anything `bob` is allowed to see. To move files to your account it's best to do it with `sudo`. Like: `sudo cp -r ~bob/Documents/Some\ Folder ~/Documents/` to copy `Some Folder` in `bob`'s documents to your `Documents` folder.

Comment: actually the permission of the home folders are usually set to be readable by everyone. MacOS doesn't do a good job at protecting privacy.

Answer (score 1):

The home folders of all users are stored in `/Users`. Assuming you have the technical and legal rights to access files of other users, you can do this by changing into their home folder (`cd /Users/joe` or `cd ~joe`) and accessing the files there.

Comment: Strangely enough I cannot access the files even though I am admin on the computer.

Comment: Then you don't have the technical rights to do so (check folder permissions to verify).

Comment: @LoveLearning Even admin users do not have access rights to other users folders in Terminal. You can invoke `sudo` privileges to access them provided, as patrix said, you have technical and legal rights to do so.

Comment: Yes I have all rights. I was just too lazy to log out and then in again to the other user where I had saved a PDF   file.